# AWS File already exists or not (Swift)

Tags: amazon-s3

I am uploading too many files on AWS S3 and that too of different types.

I am trying to restrict re-uploading to AWS if the same object already persist there.

For this I got listObjectsV2() function but it's response seems too long. If there are 200+ data, this function doesn't seems to be feasible. So I am searching some function, to which I can pass path and it will give me if exist or not.

The default behaviour of AWS is to override the file, but I need to restrict this.

I am new with AWS S3, please do add solutions and thoughts.

I tried listObjectsV2().

I am looking for some function like:
func isAlreadyExist(url: String) {
return true/false
}

Comment: [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html) is how you ask S3 if an object exists.  Unless you have thousands of objects or more and are uploading only a few, it's probably faster to list objects first, though.

Comment: Do you have example code @AnonCoward ?

Comment: You've not specified a language you're after.

Comment: I am developing for iPhone app, Swift language.